# How to control logging level for conditionally skipped unit tests in Maven / Surefire

Tags: java, maven, logging, maven-surefire-plugin, junit-jupiter

I have some JUnit unit tests which are annotated like this to be executed only if there is a specific system property defined. Usually, those tests are only executed on demand by a developer on the local machine by enabling the property, but are not executed during the regular Maven build.

```
@EnabledIfSystemProperty( named = "dev.test.integration", matches = "true" )
public class SomeComplexTest
{
    // whatever...
}
```

Now, those tests are skipped, and this leads to the following warning in Maven logs:

```
[WARNING] Tests run: 140, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2
```

Question: is there any way to control the particular logging level for such cases (intentionally skipped JUnit tests), e.g. so that it is not WARN but INFO. My goal is simply to have a completely "green" Maven build, this warning is not relevant to me.

[image]

Comment: You have to change [JUnit Jupiter](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues) and yes skipped tests produce a warning.

Comment: Why not simply naming them like `SomeComplexDevTest` and they can be executed via IDE..and why those tests are only executing on a dev machine? Why not on a CI ... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, it's "historically grown" situation which I inherited "as is"... I agree, that there definitely is potential for improvement.

Comment: Move conditional tests into a separate maven module